# How to get items from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I used `jQuery.parseJSON` to parse a JSON of objects that looks like this (Chrome Developers Console):

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
    feedback_q1: "lol"
    subtotal: "13"
    __proto__: Object
1: Object
    feedback_q1: "lal"
    subtotal: "3"
    __proto__: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
```

How can I pick, using javascript or jQuery, each object (not using loops) and its properties?

Comment: What command are you using to show this in the console? I'm only asking so I know what variable name to use to answer the question

Comment: Um, `json_objects[0].feedback_q1` and so on? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: If you don't want to use a loop you would need to access the object you require directly by it's index in the parent array. Also note that the question would be a lot clearer if you posted the actual object instead of the console version of it.

Comment: @Boldewyn that solved it, so simple... I tried all the complicated stuff instead :P thanks.

Comment: You cannot pick each object without any kind of loop. You can target specific object regarding its index but just looks like it wasn't your question... And just as a side note, JSON is a specific notation for object (btw yours isn't JSON valid here), what you have here is an array of javascript objects

Comment: @A.Wolff - True, I used `jQuery.parseJSON` to parse the actual object and this is the console.log(). I will fix the OP. Thanks

Comment: @odedta Ok, your object is surely JSON valid, the console displays it like that indeed. Like Rory said, more helpful to post actual object instead of console version. Anyway, glad you have fixed your issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
JSONObject[0]
```

should retrieve the 1st object in your JSON object. You can then get its properties by just doing

```
JSONObject[0].subtotal
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you want to get `prop1` value from `X`th element than `json_objects[X].prop1`. Is there a real-life scenario when you want to do this?

Maybe you want ed to get the element where...

If you want to get element where `prop1` value is `'lol'` then you can use JQuery `grep`

```
$.grep(json_objects, function(o){ return o.prop1 == 'lol'; });
```

The result of `$.grep` is an array with the items found which match your criteria.

Comment: Yeah, there is no need for a loop for this scenario. Thanks DDan. :)

Comment: @odedta Not sure i understand your comment but `$.grep` is looping the array internally. So like said, if you want to pick up all elements or filter array item, you have no choice to use a kind of loop.